# Why does Azure Powershell script think I'm not logged-in?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I'm building an Azure Powershell script to add a DB firewall rule.

I first of all [login using `Add-AzureRmAccount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/powershell-azure-resource-manager#log-in-to-your-azure-account):

```
$userName = "j---@s---.--"
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "---------" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($userName, $securePassword)
Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $cred
```

This returns the following, which I assume means that I have successfully logged-in:

```
Environment           : AzureCloud
Account               : j---@s---.--
TenantId              : [GUID]
SubscriptionId        : [GUID]
SubscriptionName      : Visual Studio Ultimate mit MSDN
CurrentStorageAccount :
```

At this stage I can query for my subscription:

```
Get-AzureRmSubscription –SubscriptionName "Visual Studio Ultimate mit MSDN" | Select-AzureRmSubscription
```

Which returns

```
Account      : j---@s---.--
Environment  : AzureCloud
Subscription : [GUID]
Tenant       : [GUID]
```

So far, so good.

However, whenever the script calls anything at the resource-group level, such as

```
Find-AzureRmResource -ResourceNameContains "-----NorthEurope"
```

then it responds with

> Run Login-AzureRmAccount to login.

The exception detail is

> + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Find-AzureRmResource], PSInvalidOperationException
>
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.FindAzureResourceCmdlet

Which doesn't help me at all.

I've even explicitly called

```
Login-AzureRmAccount $cred
```

prior to the `Find-AzureRmResource` call, but this makes no difference.

Of course, what I'm ultimately looking to do is call

```
New-AzureRmSqlServerFirewallRule    -ResourceGroupName "-----NorthEurope" `
                                    -ServerName "-----.database.windows.net" `
                                    -FirewallRuleName "test1" `
                                    -StartIpAddress "-.-.-.-" `
                                    -EndIpAddress "-.-.-.-"
```

But that encounters the same exception.

Can anyone explain why I keep getting asked to run `Login-AzureRmAccount` after I've apparently successfully added the account?

---

#### Solution

What got it working for me, as @Tomer alluded to in the comments, was to forcefully re-get all AzureRm modules.

Comment: what kind of account are you using for auth?

Comment: A business/work account - not a Microsoft Live account.

Comment: https://blog.kloud.com.au/2016/07/12/powershell-error-run-login-azurermaccount-to-login-in-azurerm-when-already-logged-in/